# redux-saga+next.js: action is triggered but store is inaccessible & frozen

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, next.js

### summarization:

I am trying to combine `Next.js`+`Redux-saga(+combineReducer)`. the app successfully renders the page, but `props.store` seems to be inaccessible, and it doesn't reflect the result of *redux actions*.

I've taken examples from these resources(probably the only real-code examples that I've found online):

1. `Next.js` official github: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-saga
2. Codesandbox next-redux-saga example: https://codesandbox.io/s/y16j84949?from-embed

First I thought my initialization was wrong, so I've tried different arguments with `withReduxSaga`, such as `withReduxSaga({ async: true})`, `withReduxSaga()`, `withReduxSaga` and none of them worked.
Second I thought maybe the component has to be provided in *class* form, not *function* form, so I've switched both document and component in that way too but still doesn't work.

my full code is available here, in case detailed examination is needed:
https://codesandbox.io/s/next-redux-saga-5twxj

### actual codes:

*reducer* is combined via `combineReducer`, and using my custom *enhancer*

```
// custom enhancer - util.js
const enhanceAll = (head, targets) => targets.reduce((ac, cv) => cv(ac), head);

// reducer is combined via combineReducers - in root reducer
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  count: countReducer,
});
```

```
// store/index.js
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import rootReducer, { exampleInitialState } from './reducers';
import rootSaga from './sagas';

const bindMiddleware = middleware => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require('redux-devtools-extension');
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware));
  }
  return applyMiddleware(...middleware);
};

function configureStore(initialState = exampleInitialState) {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    bindMiddleware([sagaMiddleware]),
  );

  store.sagaTask = sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

  return store;
}

export default configureStore;
```

```
// providing the redux-saga store
// pages/_app.js
import React from 'react';
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import withReduxSaga from 'next-redux-saga';
import { enhanceAll } from '../util';

import createStore from '../store';

import '../styles/common.scss';

class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {};

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps({ ctx });
    }

    return { pageProps };
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, store } = this.props;

    return (
      <Container>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Provider>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const enhancers = [withRedux(createStore), withReduxSaga];
const enhanced = enhanceAll(MyApp, enhancers);
export default enhanced;
```

```
// custom component using redux-saga
// omitted its directory because it is irrelevant to the problem.
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { enhanceAll } from '../util';
import { addNum, subNum } from '../store/actions';

class SagaComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { dispatch, store } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{JSON.stringify(this.props)}</span>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(addNum(1))}>add count</button>
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(subNum(1))}>sub count</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const enhancers = [connect(state => state)];
const enhanced = enhanceAll(SagaComponent, enhancers);
export default enhanced;
```

*action creator* and *saga* don't contain anything particular, follows the normal convention.

### error:

From what I can see from *redux webdev chrome extension*, the action itself is properly fired but `redux-saga` doesn't reflect the action. plus, *redux store* doesn't work as intended, the values inside *redux store* doesn't change at all.